# HTML Discord Webhooks

Tags: html, discord

I am looking to find a way to send a uploaded image (from a input type file box) through a discord webhook into a channel - along these steps:

1. Upload the image through a HTML input box with the type 'file'
2. Click a button that sends the uploaded image through the discord webhook

Is there anyway to do this? I have tried using a var media = media (media is my input box id) but have not had any luck.

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: I have tried using a 'var media = media' inline with my input id box however this is not operational (doesn't work) - https://prnt.sc/fCt4W1lXYGR7

Comment: Please don't show images. Copy and paste the relevant code here. For URL, you may replace it with something like "API_URL" in case it has some sensitive information.

Answer (score -1):

To get your file from the input you should do the following.

```js
    function sendMessage() { 
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    request.open("POST", "discord.com/api/webhooks/1091064728685662268/…"); 
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json'); 
        const inputFile = document.querySelector('input#media');
        const media = inputFile.files[0];
        request.send(JSON.stringify(media)); 
    }
```

Comment: Would it be to much to ask you to re-write the sendMessage code to facilitate this?

 function sendMessage() {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1091064728685662268/tsTHR_xwZKeDTMvTBCyvJVQGOYYxkiAdigG16TC6sPdjrcDpQ-xPMyM_KeQk5OZKf29z");
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        const inputFile = document.querySelector('input#media')
        const media = inputFile.files[0];
        request.send(JSON.stringify(media));
    }

Comment: You should share the code, not an image, then it is easy to modify and fix the code. I have already done it with the code you have shared in your comment.